# Using @type for declare type of class method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-method, checkjs, ts-check

When I use `@type` to declare type of class method in JavaScript with `d.ts` (see [Type Checking JavaScript Files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html)), the parameter types are determined incorrectly, if I use the short form of the method entry. If I use a form with `function`, everything works correctly.

***It's bug, or implemented so intentionally?***

> PS: using an interface for a class with methods defined in it also does not work

### common test.d.ts

```
declare module 'MyTest' {

  interface MyTest_FN1 {
    (a: [string, ...Array<string>]): string[]
  }

  interface TestFN {
    (name: string, ...args: string[]): string[]
  }
}
```

### It doesn't work:

```js
/// <reference path="./test.d.ts"/>
// @ts-check

/** test class */
class MyTest {

  /** @type {import('MyTest').MyTest_FN1} */
  fn1(args) {
    return testFn(...args)
  }

}

/** @type {import('MyTest').TestFN} */
function testFn(name, ...args) {
  return [name, ...args]
}
```

```sh
npx tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit ./test.js
> test.js:9:19 - error TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed
```

[image]

### If you add @implements, the problem remains:

```
  interface MyTestCLS {
   fn1: MyTest_FN1
  }
```

```js
/** @typedef {import('MyTest').MyTestCLS} IMyTest */
/** @implements {IMyTest} */
class MyTest {

  /** @type {import('MyTest').MyTest_FN1} */
  fn1(args) {
    // args hav a type??
    return testFn(...args)
  }

}
```

[image]

### It works:

```js
/// <reference path="./test.d.ts"/>
// @ts-check

/** test class */
class MyTest {

  /** @type {import('MyTest').MyTest_FN1} */
  fn1 = function test(args) {
    // args have a type??
    return testFn(...args)
  }

}

/** @type {import('MyTest').TestFN} */
function testFn(name, ...args) {
  return [name, ...args]
}
```

[image]